# Python - Modifying a Turtle program to turn around when it hits a wall

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I created 2 turtle's that keep moving until one of them hits a wall which causes them to stop completely.

My question is how could I make it so when it hits a wall/the other turtle, it turns instead of stopping and continues? I have a rough idea of how to do it with 1 turtle however whenever I tried it with 2, it just isn't working.

```
import random
import turtle

def moveRandom(wn, t):
    coin = random.randrange(0,2)
    if coin == 0:
        t.left(90)
    else:
        t.right(90)

    t.forward(50)

def areColliding(t1, t2):
    if t1.distance(t2) < 2:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def isInScreen(w, t):
    leftBound = - w.window_width() / 2
    rightBound = w.window_width() / 2
    topBound = w.window_height() / 2
    bottomBound = -w.window_height() / 2

    turtleX = t.xcor()
    turtleY = t.ycor()

    stillIn = True
    if turtleX > rightBound or turtleX < leftBound:
        stillIn = False
    if turtleY > topBound or turtleY < bottomBound:
        stillIn = False
    return stillIn

t1 = turtle.Turtle()
t2 = turtle.Turtle()
wn = turtle.Screen()

t1.shape('turtle')
t2.shape('circle')

leftBound = -wn.window_width() / 2
rightBound = wn.window_width() / 2
topBound = wn.window_height() / 2
bottomBound = -wn.window_height() / 2

t1.up()
t1.goto(random.randrange(leftBound, rightBound),
        random.randrange(bottomBound, topBound))
t1.setheading(random.randrange(0, 360))
t1.down()

t2.up()
t2.goto(random.randrange(leftBound, rightBound),
        random.randrange(bottomBound, topBound))
t2.setheading(random.randrange(0, 360))
t2.down()


while isInScreen(wn, t1) and isInScreen(wn, t2):
    moveRandom(wn, t1)
    moveRandom(wn, t2)

wn.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Please clarify. Are you saying that if *either* turtle hits the wall then it turns around and the other continues as is, and if the turtles hit each other they both turn around? What do you mean by "it just isn't working"? Explain exactly what is wrong.

Comment: With my current code, it stops once the turtle hits the wall when I run it. I'm trying to make it so that the turtle turns around when it hits the wall or when one turtle collides with another turtle.

Comment: You must actually be aware that there are so manythings to redo in your code, that you cannot achieve directly your (two) objectives without considering many other aspects. My answer and the associated code below, is probably the most direct and dry way of doing what you want (with no [object oriented](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm) considerations).

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to reorganize your code, so as to not repeat yourself.

```
import random
import turtle
```

Let us build the properties of the world

```
wn          = turtle.Screen()
leftBound   = -wn.window_width() / 2
rightBound  = wn.window_width() / 2
topBound    = wn.window_height() / 2
bottomBound = -wn.window_height() / 2
```

And of its living creatures

```
t1 = turtle.Turtle()
t1.shape('turtle')
t2 = turtle.Turtle()
t2.shape('circle')

delta_move = 50

# Let us build a list so as to have all turtles in hands in one object
turtles = [
    t1,
    t2,
    #t3,
    #t4,
    #...
]

for t in turtles:
    t.speed(0) # To make turtles be faster (0 is the FASTEST SPEED)
    t.setheading(random.randrange(0, 360))
    # We do not need what follows anymore, since collisions
    #  will be managed thereafter
    ##t.goto(random.randrange(leftBound, rightBound),
    ##        random.randrange(bottomBound, topBound))
```

Some physical constraints

```
def isCollidingOtherTurtle(t):
    # Let us define the reciprocity between turtles
    #  using the just-defined list "turtles" above
    other_turtles = [t_ for t_ in turtles if t_ is not t]
    # This python function called any,
    #  checks whether there is at least one 
    #   other turtle at a distance lower than 2.
    #    In this case, any(...) returns True
    return any([t.distance(ot) < 2\
                for ot in other_turtles])


def isInScreen(t):
    # There is no need to redefine the bounds
    #  since they already have a global scope 
    #   definition working in the local
    #    scope of this function 
    #     [see global versus local variables]
    ## leftBound   = - w.window_width() / 2
    ## rightBound  = w.window_width() / 2
    ## topBound    = w.window_height() / 2
    ## bottomBound = -w.window_height() / 2

    turtleX = t.xcor()
    turtleY = t.ycor()

    stillIn = True
    if turtleX > rightBound or turtleX < leftBound:
        stillIn = False
    if turtleY > topBound or turtleY < bottomBound:
        stillIn = False
    return stillIn
```

Define each generic turtle's brain

```
def getDirection():
    #return random.random()*360. - 180 # returns a float between -180 and 180
    return random.choice([-180,-90,0,90,180])

def moveRandom(t):
    # A generic turtle moves forward 
    #  if it is going to collide 
    #   with no other turtle
    if not isCollidingOtherTurtle(t):
        if isInScreen(t):        
            t.left(getDirection())    
            t.forward(delta_move)
        else:
            t.backward(delta_move)
    else:
        t.backward(delta_move)
```

And let us define how to animate this world, and animate it

```
def anim(delta_time=60):
    wn.tracer(0, 0)
    for t in turtles:
        moveRandom(t)
    wn.update()
    wn.ontimer(anim, delta_time) # delta_time is in milliseconds

anim()
turtle.mainloop()
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question wasn't as clear but the code I currently have stops as soon as the turtle hits the edge so I'm trying to adjust it. 

I'm trying to change it so that the turtle turns around when it hits the wall or when one turtle collides with another turtle based on my current code. I can't quite remember what I did to make it stop. 

Thanks for the suggestion, it helped me reorganize some parts of my code to make it easier to understand when I look back.

Comment: @Aleckandre97 Your question is perfectly clear. But you cannot achieve your objective given the current organization and structure of your code. **For example**, with `while isInScreen(wn, t1) and isInScreen(wn, t2):` your loop is broken once any turtle is outside. But you need to figure out that there is a turtle outside to reoriente it backward, which is thus impossible since you just broke the loop. Do you see what I mean ?

Comment: @Aleckandre97 My answer (tested) fully considers your two conditions, namely: **(1)** turtles turn around when it hits a wall and; **(2)** turtles turn around when it is going to collide with another turtle.

Comment: I'm not a fan of `while True:` infinite loops in turtle code -- I believe in turning control over to `mainloop()` and using turtle's timer events to keep things moving about the screen.  It's just a small change given your code's tidy organization.

Comment: @cdlane. Is this what you meant ?

Comment: Yes basically, though each turtle could be on it's own timer -- an opportunity to fine tune their relative speed if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rework of your code that I believe does as you desire.  Most of my other changes are simplifications of your code.  One major change is I tossed the `while()` loop that was moving the turtles and put them on their own timers instead:

```
import random
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def moveRandom(wn, t):
    coin = random.randrange(0, 2)

    [t.left, t.right][coin](90)

    t.forward(50)

    if not isInScreen(t) or areColliding(t1, t2):
        t.undo()  # pretend it never happened
        t.left(180)  # turn around
        t.forward(50)  # go the other way

    wn.ontimer(lambda: moveRandom(wn, t), 100)

def areColliding(t1, t2):
    return t1.distance(t2) < 2

def isInScreen(t):
    turtleX, turtleY = t.position()

    return leftBound < turtleX < rightBound and bottomBound < turtleY < topBound

t1 = Turtle('turtle', visible=False)
t2 = Turtle('circle', visible=False)
wn = Screen()

leftBound, rightBound = -wn.window_width() // 2, wn.window_width() // 2
bottomBound, topBound = -wn.window_height() // 2, wn.window_height() // 2

t1.up()
t1.goto(random.randrange(leftBound, rightBound), random.randrange(bottomBound, topBound))
t1.setheading(random.randrange(0, 360))
t1.showturtle()
t1.down()

t2.up()
t2.goto(random.randrange(leftBound, rightBound), random.randrange(bottomBound, topBound))
t2.setheading(random.randrange(0, 360))
t2.showturtle()
t2.down()

moveRandom(wn, t1)
moveRandom(wn, t2)

wn.exitonclick()
```

To handle the collisions, I call `isInScreen(t)` and `areColliding(t1, t2)` in `moveRandom(wn, t)` and simply undo the move if it causes a collision, turn around move the opposite direction.